# Edit form dynamically through subscriber

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

```
// buildForm
...
->add('book', 'entity', [
    'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Book',
    'choices' => [],
])
->addEventSubscriber(new MySubscriber());
```

The field book gets filled through javascript and gets the title of the book.
What I need to do is check if the book already exists in my db, otherwise I create it. I created a subscriber for that works well.

The problem is that I couldn't get rid of the error emitted by `$form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()`, Which is weird because I edited data in the request this way in my subscriber:

```
public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    ...
    $author = $event->getData();
    $requestForm = $this->request->request->get('mybundle_author');
    $bookTitle = $requestForm['book'];

    // if this book title doesn't exist -> create it
    ...


    $requestForm['book] = (string) $book->getId();
    $this->request->request->set('mybundle_author', $requestForm);
}
```

No matter what `FormEvents` I used, it emits the error that book value is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the option choices fixed the problem.
My subscriber is correct but in my form I had to edit the field

```
// buildForm
...
->add('book', 'entity', [
    'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Book',
    //'choices' => [], // removing this fixed the problem
])
->addEventSubscriber(new MySubscriber());
```

Answer (score 0):

I crossed a similar problem with the `entity` type.

The problem is that the new Entity is not marked as managed, and the entity type is focused on selecting existing entities. You could either pass the `ObjectManager` to the subscriber and set the entity as managed (with persist), or get rid of the validation error yourself. The latter is cleaner, but may require more work.